# How do I sort a csv file based on column headers?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a CSV file that has 231 columns number from 1 to 231. However after exporting it from another program, the resulting file has all these columns in random order, i.e. first column is sample 15, then sample 168, then sample 2

the file looks like this:

```
taxon name, sample 7, sample 205, sample 56,.....
species A, 50,307,698.......
.
.
.
.
```

How to I get to a output file that is the following way

```
taxon name, sample 1, sample 2,..., Sample 231 
Species A,658, 542,753
Species B,...,...,...
.
.
.
```

tried so far:

```bash
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", sort @F'
```

but end up with `101,..109,10,110,...,119,` and so on

the order of the species doesn't matter as long as the number for that species matches the respective sample

thank in advance for the help !

Comment: Please reformat your question so the sample data is properly formatted in code blocks so we can tell where one row ends and another begins...

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: do you have the ability to modify the current program to generate the output in sorted order?

Comment: (I actually have a perl script that can do this, but want a better worded/formatted question to be willing to share)

Comment: In a strict sense, each value in a CSV shoud only be separated by a comma
without any unwanted whitespace after the commas except for the case the whitespace
itself is a part of the value (as a leading whitespace).

Comment: `perl -F, -laE 'if($.==1){ $c2i{$_}=$i++for@F; @i=@c2i{ map$$_[0], sort{$$a[1]<=>$$b[1]} map[$_,/(\d+)/],@F[1..$#F] }; $,="," } say @F[0,@i]'` ?

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear: Do you want to sort the body of the CSV file (i.e. everything except the header line) case-insensitively? In your example, where did the `species A, 50,...` line go to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines have 231 samples, and all commas are field separators, you could try this `awk` script:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {n=$i; sub(/.* /,"",n); a[n]=i}}
  {printf("%s", $1); for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf(",%s",$a[i]); print ""}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xsv`](https://github.com/burntsushi/xsv).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="${1}"
SORT_COLUMNS=$(xsv headers "${INPUT}" | sort -k2 | awk '{printf $1","}')

xsv select "${SORT_COLUMNS}" "${INPUT}"
```

Change `sort -k2` by `sort -h -k2` for human numeric sort, or `sort -d -k2` for dictionary order, etc.